# Angular js : How to make synchronous call of factory/service methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In rum method I am calling factory methods. when in seconds method I am passing output of first method.

Int this case How can I make synchronous execution of these methods.

mycontroller.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

 angular
    .module("autoQuote")
        //Do initalization on page load
       .run(["$log","$rootScope","$state","dtoResource","questionResource",function($log,$rootScope,$state,dtoResource,"questionResource") { 
          $rootScope.AutoQuote = dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO();
          $rootScope.questions = questionResource.getQuestions($rootScope.AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.SessionInfo.StateCode);
          console.log($rootScope);
          $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (fromState.name === "") { 

            }
          });
        }])
}());
```

dtoresource.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("autoQuote")
        .factory("dtoResource",["$resource",dtoResource]);

    function dtoResource($resource)
    {
        console.log('here in dto process.');
        var prepareAutoQuoteDTO = {        
        postAutoQuoteObj         : getAutoQuoteObject(),  
       /*
       * store session info
       */
       rc1Step1DTO : function(){
        var emailId = 'test1@gmail.com';
        if (emailId && emailId != '' && emailId != 'Email Address'){
            var email           = new Email();
            email.EmailTypeCd   = 'PRIMARY';
            email.EmailAddress  = emailId;
            this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo || new Contact();
            this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails = [];
            this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails.push(email);
        } 
       return prepareAutoQuoteDTO;
     }, 

     rc1Step2DTO :  function(){
        /*
        * Store Driver information into array object
        * Collect driver info into local array and then reassign them to actual DTO object
        */
        this.postAutoQuoteObj.SessionInfo.UseExistingSession = false;
        this.postAutoQuoteObj.SessionInfo.PageName           = 'driver';
        this.postAutoQuoteObj.SessionInfo.PreviousPageName   = 'cars';
        //this.setCLK();
        return prepareAutoQuoteDTO;            
     }
    };
  return prepareAutoQuoteDTO;
}
}());
```

questionResource.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
    .module("autoQuote")
    .factory("questionResource",["$resource","$http","$state",questionResource]);

    function questionResource($resource,$http,$state)
    {   
        return{
         getQuestions : function(stateCode) {
             var userState = stateCode != "" ? stateCode : 'CA';
             $http.get('assets/themes/easyquote/js/questions/'+userState+'.json')
             .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;  
            }); 
        }
       }
    }
}());
```

In autoQuotecontroller below line shoud execute one after other

```
$rootScope.AutoQuote = dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO();
          $rootScope.questions = questionResource.getQuestions($rootScope.AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.SessionInfo.StateCode);
```

Comment: You need to return a [`promise`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) from the function `rc1Step1DTO`. Than you can use a code like this: `$rootScope.AutoQuote = dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO().then(function(){;
          $rootScope.questions = questionResource.getQuestions($rootScope.AutoQuote.postAutoQuoteObj.SessionInfo.StateCode);});`

Comment: thanks, how can I add promise here in above code. there are allready .then in factory.

Comment: is @Srijith answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of promises. Each method in your factory should return a promise. You could use `$q` to do that.

**Step 1**

Inject `$q` into your factory. e.g. lets do it on `dtoResource` factory like this

```
    angular
     .module("autoQuote")
     .factory("dtoResource",["$resource",'$q', dtoResource]);

    function dtoResource($resource, $q)
    .....
```

**Step 2**

Make the method return a promise like this

```
 rc1Step1DTO : function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
      var emailId = 'test1@gmail.com';
      if (emailId && emailId != '' && emailId != 'Email Address'){
        var email           = new Email();
        email.EmailTypeCd   = 'PRIMARY';
        email.EmailAddress  = emailId;
        this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo || new Contact();
        this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails = [];
        this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails.push(email);
       deferred.resolve(prepareAutoQuoteDTO);
       } 
      return deferred.promise;
   }
```

> The parameter you need for the second function (prepareAutoQuoteDTO) needs to be passed to deferred.resolve so its available for the next function in the chain

**Step 3**
Convert all your factory methods (which needs to be executed synchronously) to return a promise like above

**Step 4**
 Call those methods in the controller like this

```
 dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO()
 .then(questionResource.getQuestions)
 .then(function(){
   console.log('This should be printed after the above methods are done     executing');
  })
.fail(function(reason){
  console.log(reason + ' this is the reason that your code failed. The reason comes from a defered.reject from your chained methods');
 });
```

> **Remember**
>
> - All possible branches of your code has to either resolve or reject a promise
> - Pass parameters to the chained functions using either deferred.resolve or reject
> - Handle the failure case in the controller in the `fail` step
> - Use promises wisely

Comment: I changed code to $rootScope.AutoQuote = dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO().then(
              $rootScope.questions = questionResource.getQuestions('CA');
              console.log($rootScope);
          ) SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. what I am missing here.

Comment: `dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO().then(questionResource.getQuestions).then(function(){console.log('done')});`

Set the rootscope values in the respective methods in the factories. in `rc1Step1DTO`, do `deferred.resolve('CA')` so that it is supplied as a parameter to `questionResource.getQuestions`

Comment: resolved $rootScope.AutoQuote = dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO().then(function(){
              $rootScope.questions = questionResource.getQuestions('CA'); 
              console.log($rootScope);
          })  
          .then(function(){
            console.log('This should be printed after the above methods are done     executing');
          })

Comment: but in console I see ajax request is after printing "This should be printed after the above methods are done     executing". ajax response should come then only this log should be printed.

Comment: Make sure your `getQuestions` method also returns a promise. The above code in your comment will execute `getQuestions` asynchronously unless you chain it to the `rc1Step1DTO` method like in my answer.

Comment: I updated files here http://plnkr.co/edit/kLc6DPqzQgLNpUBaLtZi?p=catalogue. please let me know if i am missing something.  in console $scope i am not getting data in AutoQuote
 
 Object { then=function(),  catch=function(),  finally=function()}
catch
 
 function(callback)
finally
 
 function(callback)
then
 
 function(callback, errback, progressback)

Comment: Please add the dependencies to your plunker correctly. I can take a look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117180/discussion-between-greatym-com-and-srijith).

Comment: Result of the chat: Here is the plunker to do this http://plnkr.co/edit/jFLcWPb86RRvXT16sDcc?p=preview